# Java Script Sorting algorithm visualizer

Tags: javascript, sorting, timeout

```js
k = []
len = 100;
time = true

cont = document.getElementsByClassName("cont")[0];
cont.innerHTML = "";
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    t = Math.round(Math.random() * 800 ) + 5
    k.push(t);
    cont.innerHTML += "<div class='block' style = 'height:" + t + "px'></div>"
}


function reset(){
    k = []
    cont.innerHTML = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        t = Math.round(Math.random() * 800 ) + 5
        k.push(t);
        cont.innerHTML += "<div class='block' style = 'height:" + t + "px'> </div>"
    }

}

function bubble(){
    function iloop(i){
        if(i < len){
        setTimeout(function(){
            function jloop(j){
                if(j < len){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    if (k[j] > k[j + 1]) {
                        let tmp = k[j];
                        k[j] = k[j + 1];
                        k[j + 1] = tmp;
                    }
                    cont.innerHTML = "";
                    for (let p = 0; p < len; p++) {
                        cont.innerHTML += "<div class='block' style = 'height:" + k[p] + "px'></div>"
                    }
                    j++;
                    jloop(j);
                }, 100);
                }
            }
            jloop(0);



            i++;
            iloop(i);
        }, 100);
        }
    }
    iloop(0);
}
```

```css
.cont {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
  display: block;
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 0px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  align-content: center; }
  .cont .block {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    margin: auto 1px;
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 5px;
    bottom: 0px; }
```

```html
<button class="reset" onclick="reset()">Reset Array
</button> 
<button class="bubble" onclick="bubble()">Bubble Sort
</button> 
<div class="cont"> 
 </div>
```

I am using this simple code to make a javascript visualizer for sorting algorithm but the problem is that it is very choppy and skips multiples frames while running even at a delay of 100ms. I have an i7 7700hq and gtx 1060 so I know that the problem is mostly not my laptop but my approach to it so what approach should I take

Here is a code pen version if your snippets are not working
https://codepen.io/varunagarwal/pen/gOaQqbG

Edit: someone told me to make it a runnable snippet so there you go

Comment: Sadly, though, [Stack Snippets aren't working (reliably) right now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397555/snippets-not-working). :-(

Comment: You have overlapping timeouts there, which seems problematic. You only need one `setTimeout` to the browser and allow it to paint. You may find a generator function yielding in the inner loop works better: you'd call the generator's `next` in a timer loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overlapping `setTimeout` timers, and a **lot** of them being scheduled. You only want to yield back to the browser when there's a change to show, and you only want to show a given change once.

Since you're using ES2015+, I'd probably use a generator function to do the sort, yielding when something changes:

```
function *sortGen() {
    for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        for (let j = 0; j < len; ++j) {
            if (k[j] > k[j + 1]) {
                let tmp = k[j];
                k[j] = k[j + 1];
                k[j + 1] = tmp;
                yield j; // *** Yield to caller, saying what changed
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then the code calling it would call its `next` method, do the update, and then schedule callback for just before the next animation frame via `requestAnimationFrame` (unless you want to artificially slow it down, in which case `setTimeout` is fine). Animation frames happen 60 times/second (roughly every 16.666667ms) provided the browser isn't busy doing something else. Here's `bubble` using the generator from the `sortGen` function above:

```
function bubble() {
    const gen = sortGen();
    tick();

    function tick() {
        const result = gen.next();
        if (!result.done) {
            // *** No need to recreate all the elements, just reorder the ones that got swapped
            const el = cont.children[result.value];
            const next = el.nextElementSibling;
            el.parentElement.insertBefore(next, el);
            requestAnimationFrame(tick);
        }
    }
}
```

(You could make it an async generator and use a `for-await-of` loop, but I don't think it really buys you much.)

Here's a live example; I've also included some comments in the code making other suggestions:

```js
"use strict"; // *** Use strict mode

// *** Declare your variables (the old code relied on The Horror of Implicit Globals, which
// strict mode fixes)
let k = []; // *** Consistently use semicolons (or consistently rely on ASI)
let len = 100;
let time = true;

const cont = document.getElementsByClassName("cont")[0];
// *** Don't duplicate code, just use `reset`
reset();

function reset(){
    k = [];
    // *** Never use += on `innerHTML`
    let html = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // *** Declare your variables
        const t = Math.round(Math.random() * 800 ) + 5;
        k.push(t);
        html += makeBlock(t);
    }
    cont.innerHTML = html;
}

function makeBlock(value) {
    return "<div class='block' style = 'height:" + value + "px'></div>";
}

function *sortGen() {
    for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        for (let j = 0; j < len; ++j) {
            if (k[j] > k[j + 1]) {
                let tmp = k[j];
                k[j] = k[j + 1];
                k[j + 1] = tmp;
                yield j; // *** Yield to caller, saying what changed
            }
        }
    }
}

function bubble() {
    const gen = sortGen();
    tick();

    function tick() {
        const result = gen.next();
        if (!result.done) {
            // *** No need to recreate all the elements, just reorder the ones that got swapped
            const el = cont.children[result.value];
            const next = el.nextElementSibling;
            el.parentElement.insertBefore(next, el);
            requestAnimationFrame(tick);
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.cont {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
  display: block;
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 0px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  align-content: center;
} /* *** Don't hide closing } at the end of a line */
.cont .block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  margin: auto 1px;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 5px;
  bottom: 0px;
} /* *** Don't hide closing } at the end of a line */
```

```html
<button class="reset" onclick="reset()">Reset Array
</button> 
<button class="bubble" onclick="bubble()">Bubble Sort
</button> 
<div class="cont"> 
</div>
```

[Also on CodePen](https://codepen.io/tjcrowder/pen/zYvMeQN).

For what it's worth, the async generator approach looks something like this:

```
const nextFrame = cb => new Promise(resolve => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        cb();
        resolve();
    });
});

function bubble() {
    (async () => {
        for await (const value of sortGen()) {
            await nextFrame(() => {
                const el = cont.children[value];
                const next = el.nextElementSibling;
                el.parentElement.insertBefore(next, el);
            });
        }
    })()
    .catch(error => {
        // Handle/report error here...
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

```js
"use strict"; // *** Use strict mode

// *** Declare your variables (the old code relied on The Horror of Implicit Globals, which
// strict mode fixes)
let k = []; // *** Consistently use semicolons (or consistently rely on ASI)
let len = 100;
let time = true;

const cont = document.getElementsByClassName("cont")[0];
// *** Don't duplicate code, just use `reset`
reset();

function reset(){
    k = [];
    // *** Never use += on `innerHTML`
    let html = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // *** Declare your variables
        const t = Math.round(Math.random() * 800 ) + 5;
        k.push(t);
        html += makeBlock(t);
    }
    cont.innerHTML = html;
}

function makeBlock(value) {
    return "<div class='block' style = 'height:" + value + "px'></div>";
}

function *sortGen() {
    for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        for (let j = 0; j < len; ++j) {
            if (k[j] > k[j + 1]) {
                let tmp = k[j];
                k[j] = k[j + 1];
                k[j + 1] = tmp;
                yield j; // *** Yield to caller, saying what changed
            }
        }
    }
}

const nextFrame = cb => new Promise(resolve => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        cb();
        resolve();
    });
});

function bubble() {
    (async () => {
        for await (const value of sortGen()) {
            await nextFrame(() => {
                const el = cont.children[value];
                const next = el.nextElementSibling;
                el.parentElement.insertBefore(next, el);
            });
        }
    })()
    .catch(error => {
        // Handle/report error here...
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

```css
.cont {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
  display: block;
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 0px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  align-content: center;
} /* *** Don't hide closing } at the end of a line */
.cont .block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  margin: auto 1px;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 5px;
  bottom: 0px;
} /* *** Don't hide closing } at the end of a line */
```

```html
<button class="reset" onclick="reset()">Reset Array
</button> 
<button class="bubble" onclick="bubble()">Bubble Sort
</button> 
<div class="cont"> 
</div>
```

[Also on CodePen](https://codepen.io/tjcrowder/pen/ZEbmPBL).