# Why doesn't sorting work correctly when I change state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, react-state-management

I have the BubbleSort component, but when I start the sorting process something goes wrong and my sorting works incorrect. I'm sure, the algorithm itself is written correctly. I suppose something is wrong with the setting state process, but can't figure out what it can be.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import ArrayView from "../ArrayView/ArrayView";

export default class BubbleSort extends Component{
  state = {
    elements: this.props.elements
  }

    sort = () => {
    const length = this.state.elements.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      for (let j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
        if (this.state.elements[i].value > this.state.elements[j].value) {
          this.swap(i, j);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  swap = (first, second) => {
    this.setState((state) => {
      const newElements = [...state.elements];

      const temp = newElements[first];
      newElements[first] = newElements[second];
      newElements[second] = temp;

      return {
        elements: newElements
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { elements } = this.state;

    return (
      <ArrayView elements={elements} onSort={this.sort} />
    )
  }
}
```

[image: Edit sparkling-sea-dt2mg]

Comment: It's **great** doing a runnable example, but please do it **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: What is the problem with this example? On every click, it seems that you make an iteration of the algorithm

Comment: You can add a delay between each state update using a `Promise` and `async-await` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're swapping elements in state every time and **not** swapping them in the array you're actually sorting in `sort` (the local `elements` array). So subsequent operations on the local `elements` array in `sort` continue to use the old values, which means the bubblesort won't work properly.

Unless you want your component to update the DOM on every swap (which would mean substantial changes to it), change state just once, setting the new array when you're done sorting it.

Comment: The problem is that even if I use `this.state.element` instead of `const elements = [...this.state.elements]` I get the same result. (I edit my question accordingly). It is exactly what I want - to change state every swap to animate the sorting process.

I thought that I can do the swap twice: firstly in the sort function, and secondly in the swap function actually in the state of the component. But this approach seems strange to me because of duplication. Is there any way to achieve that result without such duplication?

Comment: @RomanAndreev - [State updates may be asynchronous and may be batched up](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). Once you've called `setState` to set a new state, `this.state` is no longer up-to-date. It won't reliably be up-to-date until you receive the state completion callback (which you can pass as a second argument to `setState`. Moreover, your component won't re-render *during* your `sort` call. If you want to show progress as you're going, you'll have to keep the state of the bubblesort as state information and wait until each state...

Comment: ...change is complete before doing the next one. It's a complete rewrite of your component.

Comment: @RomanAndreev - You may find [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62025637/how-to-pause-javascript-for-loop-animating-bubble-sort/62025984#62025984) useful. It's also about showing the progress of a bubblesort in a React component. I think the answer above answers the question you asked (why isn't it working), and that answer shows you one way to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to show the sorting process step by step, you can add a delay between each state update after swapping, using a `Promise` and `async-await` syntax.

In `BubbleSort` component, add following two functions:

1. To add a delay between each state update after swap operation

   ```
   sleep(seconds) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000);
      });
   };
   ```
2. Sort function that will call the `sleep()` function after each swap operation inside the nested loop

   ```
   async sort() {
     const elements = [...this.state.elements];
     const length = elements.length;

      for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
          if (this.state.elements[i].value > this.state.elements[j].value) {
             const temp = elements[i];
             elements[i] = elements[j];
             elements[j] = temp;

            this.setState({ elements });

            await this.sleep(1.5);
          }
        }
      }
   };
   ```

#### Demo:

[image: Edit great-brattain-bodbj]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set new state in swap function.

Swap elements and set new state in sort function, like this:

```js
sort = () => {
    const elements = [...this.state.elements];

    const length = elements.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      for (let j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
        if (elements[i].value > elements[j].value) {
          const temp = elements[i];
          elements[i] = elements[j];
          elements[j] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
    this.setState({ elements });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but It is what I exactly want: to show every step during the sorting process

Comment: @RomanAndreev, well in that case your code works OK because after some click, you get sorted array correctly.